# How do I position this button in center?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, alignment

How do I position this button

[image: img]

in the center of [this page](https://dentcourses.com)?

Comment: you should also  add the related  html and css  code  the  image  alone is not enough  for an evalaution   ..

Comment: Use align:center;

Comment: I believe you want it below praktijkmanagers use text-align:center on the parent div, or enclose it inside a < center > tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule in your css is responsible:

```
.thim-sc-button.home-6-top {
   text-align:left; 
   display:inline-block; 
   margin-right:18px;
}
```

You can remove the `home-6-top` class from your `button` element to center it or just remove the `text-align` and `display` properties to keep the margin.

Answer (score 0):

give this css styles to the div element containing the button

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

I tried it on your website, appears like that:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Tol,
Welcome to Stackoverflow.

You can try this
[image]